# How to create SWT browser for SonarLint for Eclipse rule description?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-juno, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

When I try to display *SonarLint* rule (by right-clicking on issue description and "*Rule description*"), I have an error on the *SonarLint Rule description* tab:

> Unable to create SWT Browser:
>
> No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME)]

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, Eclipse Juno.

Didn't dig in it very much, because I have a feeling that it should be somehow provided by defalut during SonarLint installation.

Comment: Eclipse Juno has been released 2012. Does upgrading to [Eclipse Oxygen.1a](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) fix your problem?

Comment: @howlger I was using SonarLint with Eclipse Oxygen for some time without problems, but now I wanted to install it on this Ubuntu and this is the version from repository so I would like to have it working on this version :)

Comment: [More than 100 bugs related to Linux and the browser widget has been fixed since Eclipse Juno](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?classification=Eclipse&f1=op_sys&list_id=16884678&longdesc=browser&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&o1=equals&product=Platform&query_format=advanced&resolution=FIXED&v1=Linux&version=3.8&version=3.8.1&version=3.8.2&version=4.0&version=4.1&version=4.2&version=4.2.1&version=4.2.2&version=4.3&version=4.3.1&version=4.3.2&version=4.4&version=4.4.1&version=4.4.2&version=4.5&version=4.5.1&version=4.5.2&version=4.6&version=4.7&version=4.7.1) (SonarLint bugs not included)

Comment: I have the same issue under CentOS and Eclipse Mars.2

Comment: Same issue on Kubuntu 20.04.3 and Eclipse 2021-09.

Answer (score 1):

Close the eclipse and install `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` executing the following command: `sudo apt install -y libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`. Reopen your eclipse and see if worked.

Comment: I get: `Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-1.0-0' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Also, as i managed to install it. It does not fix issue.